# How to repair corrupted (VBA) Excel/XLSM? (often "automation error (2147467259) unspecified error")

Tags: excel, vba

I crashed the *XLSM* file already several times during programming in ***Excel (2010)***. (lastly during debugging)
The result was, that it was either

- reported as corrupt (sometimes repairable) or
- crashed the whole Excel application :-/ or
- opening the VBA editor with a message "automation error (2147467259) unspecified error" and one cannot close Excel anymore without using the *Task Manager* and killing the whole Excel instance

How can I get the original or same version back or get it fixed?
(We have a version tracking system in place, but sometimes the lost changes would be quite big)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily we had some ***Excel 2016*** in place and it could be **opened there and saved** as the same *XLSM* file. Afterwards it could be opened by *Excel 2010* without a problem :)
(In *Excel 2016* there is also an **`Open and Repair...` option** that may be necessary - as mentioned by [ryguy72](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55046511/1915920)).

(**In general** it is a good idea to have a **versioning system** like Mercurial, Git or some versioning DMS etc. in place!)

Btw: We could also open and save it in ***LibreOffice*** (*6.0.6.2 64bit*), but there were too many non-*LibreOffice* compatible formattings (e.g. images collapsing with left-side row groups), features (e.g. *Named Tables*) etc. inside, so the resulting file was not very useful for us (but for others this may be enough - without big licensing/installing hassle).

Comment: Also saving in the binary `XLSB` format helps sometimes. I had already several issues with large `XLSX` or `XLSM` files that got corrupt after a while of normal use. Converting them to `XLSB` always kept them intact. • For relevant data I only trust `XLSB`.

Comment: Funny thing is, sometimes it gets corrupted (*XLSM*) in *Excel 2016*, but opening it in *Excel 2010* works :)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it is possible to fix the VBA code execution when opening the workbook.
If the `automation error` occurs it **may be just due to some uncompiled code** (in combination with triggering features like *Open*, *Select*, *Activate* events or (re)calculating formulas).

So this helps in a lot of situations (especially during development):

1. **rename** the `MyFile.xlsm` **file** to `MyFile2.xlsm`

   - => thus the `Activate Macro` dialog will appear on next open
2. **do not `Activate Macro`**, but push `F11` to (edit the code or/and) **`VBA Editor => Menu => Debugging => Compile ...`** the code
3. close the file and rename back to `MyFile.xlsm`
4. on open: choose `Activate Macro`

Comment: Wow you saved me from a lot of misery lol I had lost a whole 2 days of intense work. I do remember at some point recording a macro and i forgot to stop it and continued to write more code, saving etc. I did finally stop it but i think thats what corrupted things in my case. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the help on this one. This works with Office 365 also. I had an excel file with a huge amount of data and macros, forms modules etc. Hours of work which I thought I had lost. The advice to rename, open (not activate macros) but first open VBA editor and compile the code worked perfectly. I was worried I had wasted days of my life for nothing before I saw this fix. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1):

Open a new workbook, navigate to your corrupt file, click Open and Repair (not just Open).

[image]

Comment: Yeah. I read this somewhere and it is available in Excel 2016. In my case just opening it there was enough - maybe some auto-repair was done implicitely.

Comment: Maybe.  Excel is pretty 'smart' these days.  I started working with it in the late 90s, and compared to then, we are in a much better place now.